# What does "Accept-Language: en-securid" header ...mean?

Tags: internet-explorer, http-headers

Sifting through some server-side warnings about unrecognized client languages, I've noticed some browser clients present the following header:

```
Accept-Language: en-securid,en-us
```

It seems to be from IE8, something to do with windows and RSA SecurID?  Is there any practical implication of this header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is related to RSA's SecurID desktop application. From [this PDF](https://onyx.koli.ch/get/5594/SecurIDToken_release_notes.pdf) (I had a really tough time finding an actual website with this info), it mentions that this culture is added when installing the IE plug-in related to the SecurID application:

> When you install the web browser plug-in for Internet Explorer with the SecurID desktop application, the
>   `en-securid` language setting, which allows the browser to recognize web pages protected by RSA SecurID, is added
>   only for the local user who installs the application.